# How to build a matrix in r by using "apply" and passing vectors as arguments to a custom function

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I would like to create a matrix as follows and am not sure if I should be using the apply family of functions or some other matrix function (I want to avoid using nested for loops):

DATA INPUTS:

```
sequence <- seq(5, 25, 5)
dataset <- c(3, 6, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 10, 4)
```

CUSTOM FUNCTION:

```
calculation <- function(foo, bar) {
    result <- bar * foo * 0.5
    return(result)
}
```

GOAL:

```
str(goal)
num [1:10, 1:5] 7.5 15 20 7.5 10 12.5 15 5 25 10 ...
goal
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5]
 [1,]  7.5   15 22.5   30  37.5
 [2,] 15.0   30 45.0   60  75.0
 [3,] 20.0   40 60.0   80 100.0
 [4,]  7.5   15 22.5   30  37.5
 [5,] 10.0   20 30.0   40  50.0
 [6,] 12.5   25 37.5   50  62.5
 [7,] 15.0   30 45.0   60  75.0
 [8,]  5.0   10 15.0   20  25.0
 [9,] 25.0   50 75.0  100 125.0
[10,] 10.0   20 30.0   40  50.0
```

Comment: `outer(sequence,dataset, FUN=calculation)` maybe?

Comment: This would be far more obvious if you gave a much smaller example. `sequence` and `dataset` could have been 3 items each, and you could have actually shown the expected output as a 3x3 matrix, instead of writing out 50 lines of explanatory text.

Comment: @thelatemail :  I think the order of arguments should have been `outer(dataset, sequence, FUN=calculation)` ? But definite +1!

Comment: You are asking for `apply`, but that relies on a `matrix` or `array`. Are you intending to include `sapply` and friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that outer() was the function I was looking for (i.e. the "outer product of arrays"). The order of input arrays to outer() is important to the structure of the resulting matrix. Thank you thelatemail and Ketil B T

CORRECT VERSION:

```
goal.matrix <- outer(dataset,sequence, FUN=calculation)
```

Note: if the order of input arrays to outer() is reversed, the resulting matrix is simply the transposed version of goal.matrix.

```
transposed.goal <- outer(sequence, dataset, FUN=calculation)
transposed.goal

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]  7.5   15   20  7.5   10 12.5   15    5   25    10
[2,] 15.0   30   40 15.0   20 25.0   30   10   50    20
[3,] 22.5   45   60 22.5   30 37.5   45   15   75    30
[4,] 30.0   60   80 30.0   40 50.0   60   20  100    40
[5,] 37.5   75  100 37.5   50 62.5   75   25  125    50

goal.matrix <- t(transposed.goal)
goal.matrix

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5]
 [1,]  7.5   15 22.5   30  37.5
 [2,] 15.0   30 45.0   60  75.0
 [3,] 20.0   40 60.0   80 100.0
 [4,]  7.5   15 22.5   30  37.5
 [5,] 10.0   20 30.0   40  50.0
 [6,] 12.5   25 37.5   50  62.5
 [7,] 15.0   30 45.0   60  75.0
 [8,]  5.0   10 15.0   20  25.0
 [9,] 25.0   50 75.0  100 125.0
[10,] 10.0   20 30.0   40  50.0
```

Answer (score -2):

Do you realize you have essentially described the relevant nested for-loop? So unless you really want to use apply, you're actually done.

That is,

```
goal <- matrix(NA, 1000, 166)
for(i in 1:nrow(goal)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(goal)){
    goal[i, j] <- dataset[i] * sequence[j] * 0.004
  }
}
```